# How can I load in this text file using Java in an Android Application, in an external class?

Tags: java, android, class, adt

I've got a text file that has 173,139 words delimited by newlines. Basically, I need to load this 1.7mb file into an array of strings, for easy access. I'm trying to do this in `onCreate()` for the main activity, which might cause problems of its own because it might make starting the application really slow, but right now I'm just trying to load in the dictionary, I suppose.

I looked up the problem and found that I should use asset manager for this problem, so here's what I have in my Dictionary class:

```
public class Dictionary {
    private String[] dictionary = new String[173139];
    private String[] acceptedWordsList = new String[173139];
    private String acceptedWords = "";

    public Dictionary(Context context){
        AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
        try {
            String rawText;
            int element = 0;
            InputStream is = am.open("words.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while((rawText=reader.readLine()) != null){
                dictionary[element++] = rawText;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and I'm instantiating a Dictionary in my Main Activity in pretty much the first line in the class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary(this);
    //rest of application code
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've also tried instantiating a Dictionary like this:

`Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary(this.getApplicationContext());`

as well as:

`Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary(getApplicationContext());`

but all of these seem to cause fatal errors in my application.

So two final questions: is it okay to instantiate in the beginning of the application code like that? And if so, why doesn't that code work when I'm trying to do so?

edit: I was asked for logcat output. My apologies, this is my first "real" android program. I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I don't want to omit anything that might be helpful either:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=c99LFZzx

Comment: Where is your `onCreate()` code?

Comment: Right under the instantiation of dictionary. I was told I should put it in onCreate()? Gonna try that now. My only worry is that I'll need to access the dictionary in another method of the main class, and I don't wanna instantiate it twice... hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought: your `context.getAssets` call throws the NPE (possibly because context is null).

I think that's because you did not put `Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary(this);` in the `onCreate` method actually.

I would expect it to work (provided the file is there) if you put that code on `onCreate`, after `super.onCreate(bundle)`.

If you are worried about app initialization loading time, I suggest you use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to load your dictionary in a splash activity, so you can provide user feedback.

Comment: I've done this, but I need access to the dictionary outside of onCreate(), in another method that's called by a button. I think I'd still rather instantiate the dictionary in onCreate() though, because then it'll load up on the start of the application. Any way I could instantiate the object in onCreate() and access it in addToWords?

Comment: @Arnav well, as I said, if you load it in a splash activity, you won't have that problem at all. You can either use a class representing your dictionary statically, or pass it from the splash activity to the main activity. Whichever your solution is, if you thread it (i.e. with an AsyncTask) you will be able to initialize as null first, populate in a separate thread, and check for nulls in your other method...